# In community, what order to components get rendered in?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder, lightning-events

I have a community which has two components: A and B.

Component A fires a global event, which component B handles. But I'm finding that B successfully calls its handler only some of the time. The only reason I can think of for this is that there's something non-deterministic about community page rendering.

How does community page rendering work? Is it asynchronous, or am I hitting something else?

Comment: Rendering within a component tree is deterministic (inner elements will render before outer elements), but rendering across the tree is non-deterministic based on when components are loaded from the server. We would need specifics to know more, but it sounds like you may want to use two-way communication by having A fire its event, and B firing an event when it loads so that A can resend this event if need be.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering within a component tree is largely deterministic, as inner elements will be loaded before outer elements, but the app itself may load components non-deterministically based on the components in the cache and which components need to be retrieved from the server. I would design the events so that component A fires an event when it loads, and B fires an event when it loads, which A can then respond to. This way, if A loads before B, the event will be missed, but B will ask for another event when it loads, and get the event. If B loads before A, it will send an event that will be missed, but then A will send its event, and B will still get the event.